# http-proxy-middleware: pathFilter not working as expected

Tags: browser-sync, http-proxy-middleware, lite-server

I am trying so setup a npm-based HTML development environment using two servers. One hosts my HTML app of static files (standard way: `http://localhost:8080`) while the other exposes an application api running locally(`http://127.0.0.1:57146/api/someEntity`). The latter is beyond my control.
Calling the api URLs directly from my app brings up CORS issues. So i want to setup a proxy that redirects my calls from `http://localhost:8080/apiBase/someEntity` to `http://127.0.0.1:57146/api/someEntity`... hoping to avoid the CORS problems that way.

I am using [lite-server](https://github.com/johnpapa/lite-server#readme), which builds on top of [Browsersync](https://browsersync.io/docs/options).

Since my static app files do not need redirection, they should not be affected by the proxy.
To specify, which calls are redirected, i am trying to use the "pathFilter" field in the options. But i cannot get that functioning. Instead all calls are always proxied to `http://127.0.0.1:57146`. "pathRewrite" does not seems to work, either. So it seems like i am missing something basic here. What am i doing wrong?

Here is my config file:

```
//bs-config.cjs

const { createProxyMiddleware } = require('http-proxy-middleware');

const apiProxy = createProxyMiddleware({
  target: "http://127.0.0.1:57146/",
  pathFilter:"apiBase/",
  pathRewrite: {
    "apiBase/": "api/"
  },
  logger: "console",
  logLevel: "debug"
});

module.exports = {
  port: 8080,
  index: "parent.htm",
  startPath: "parent.htm",
  cors: true,
  server: {
    baseDir: "./dist",
    index: "parent.htm",
    cors: true,
    middleware: [ apiProxy ]      
  }
};
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With the help of a (very) patient backend guy, i finally found a solution.
We could not get "pathRewrite" to work, but after getting the filter functioning (by changing some syntax), tweaking the paths ended up in a working setup.

```
//bs-config.cjs

const { createProxyMiddleware } = require('http-proxy-middleware');

const proxy_filter = function (path, req) {
  const regx = new RegExp("/apiBase");
  return path.match(regx);
};

const proxy_options = {
  target: "http://127.0.0.1:57146/api/",
  changeOrigin: true,  
  logger: "console",
  logLevel: "debug"
}

const apiProxy = createProxyMiddleware(proxy_filter, proxy_options);

module.exports = {
  port: 8080,
  index: "parent.htm",
  startPath: "parent.htm",
  server: {
    baseDir: "./dist",
    index: "parent.htm",
    middleware: [
      apiProxy
    ]
  }
};
```

Comment: If you have correctly answered your own question, Stack Overflow encourages you to mark it as Accepted in order to help other people.